# The convergence of the power method for find eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

For a symmetric matrix $A$, with an assumption $|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2| \geq...\geq|\lambda_n|$. If we applying power method to find the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue, the k-th iteration vector $v_k$ will converge to a multiple of eigenvector, namely

\begin{align*} 
A^kv_1  & = A^k(a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 +..+ a_nx_n)\\  
      & = a_1A^kx_1 + a_2A^kx_2 +..+ a_nA^kx_n\\
      & = a_1\lambda_1^k x_1 + a_2\lambda_2^k x_2 +..+ a_n\lambda_n^k x_n\\
      & = a_1 x_1 + a_2(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k x_2 +..+ a_n(\frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_1})^k x_n
\end{align*}

The convergence property of power method should be $||v_k - q_1||_2 =  O(|λ2/λ1|^k)$, but I don't understand how could I obtain this relation from the $A^kv_1 = a_1 x_1 + a_2(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k x_2 +..+ a_n(\frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_1})^k x_n$. If calculate  $||v_k - q_1||_2$, it should be

$$||v_k - q_1||_2 = ||\lambda_1^k((a_1-\frac{1}{\lambda_1^k}) x_1 + a_2(\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1})^k x_2 +..+ a_n(\frac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_1})^k x_n)||_2$$ So, the norm is not equal to $O(|λ2/λ1|^k)$ in this cases, I don' understand where I am doing wrong? could someone help me？

Comment: The idea is that $\|v_k - a_1 x_1\| = O(|\lambda_2/\lambda_1|^k)$.

Comment: @paulinho so, I only need to care about the the direction of the eigenvector?

Comment: Yes, usually in the power method we only care about the direction. This is usually evidenced by the fact that in every iteration, we normalize $v_k$